# Database Access Layer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce, edmx

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and i have created a .sdf and .edmx for my database. 
I was wondering what would be the best way to set the relationships between the entities. 
I have tried just setting the association with the multiplicity set and get an error saying that they are not mapped. 
Also how do you set the foreign keys. 
I am trying to create a estate agent like system to book appointments online and in branch. I am creating it in C#.

Comment: I got it to work thanks. I was originally using edmx and sdf. I changed it to DBML and mdf and it works. Let's me set the foreign keys when add the entity's it adds the association itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Assume you are going Database first.
If so, if you just simply creat your foreign keys and constraints in your database and then try to add your entities again, then your edmx file will have the relationships and everything.

Comment: See when I add the table should I include the foreign keys in there aswell

Comment: Also how do you crate the foreign keys and constraints

Comment: If you add the foreign key and constraints in your database schema, when you drop your tables into the edmx, they will be automatically generated.

Comment: Aram is there any way that i could email you ?

Comment: still cant get it to add the foreign keys correctly